# pentaho kettle + error while using ftp put , get ,delete file plugin

Tags: kettle

I'm  getting the following error randomly on using ftp get, put, and delete file via FTP.

> org.pentaho.di - FTP Delete - java.net.ConnectException: Connection
>   refused at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
>   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) at
>   com.enterprisedt.util.proxy.PlainSocket.createPlainSocket(PlainSocket.java:103)
>   at
>   com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPControlSocket.newPassiveDataSocket(FTPControlSocket.java:946)
>   at
>   com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPControlSocket.createDataSocketPASV(FTPControlSocket.java:854)
>   at
>   com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPControlSocket.createDataSocket(FTPControlSocket.java:574)
>   at
>   com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.setupDataSocket(FTPClient.java:2572)
>   at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.initPut(FTPClient.java:2627) at
>   com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.putData(FTPClient.java:2700) at
>   com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.putStream(FTPClient.java:2439) at
>   com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.put(FTPClient.java:2407) at
>   com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.put(FTPClient.java:2368) at
>   org.pentaho.di.job.entries.ftpput.JobEntryFTPPUT.execute(JobEntryFTPPUT.java:812)
>   at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:693) at
>   org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:830) at
>   org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:577) at
>   org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.jobexecutor.JobExecutor.executeJob(JobExecutor.java:238)
>   at
>   org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.jobexecutor.JobExecutor.processRow(JobExecutor.java:87)
>   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:60) at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0):

it seems nothing related to pentaho, **connection refused** means that, looks some kind of problem from the ftp server side.

Answer (score 0):

I can user ftp get plugin when run locally but was failed remotely,the error message--`FTP:User cannot log in.`